# Perform an OR query between a scalar field and fulltext search?

Tags: solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

```
Book.search do
  any do
    fulltext "tupac"
    with :tags, ["southpark"]
  end
end
```

Since `any` accepts only fulltext, and `any_of` accepts only scalar fields, how do I find books with the word `tupac` OR tagged with `southpark`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Book.search do
  any do
    fulltext "tupac", minimum_match: 0
    with :tags, ["southpark"]
  end
end
```

Comment: I'll try it, but isn't that going to return all records? Seems like every records would match `fulltext "tupac", minimum_match: 0`.

Comment: Ok so I was wrong `fulltext "tupac", minimum_match: 0` doesn't match every document, but still, mixing fulltext and with doesn't work.